# 'Waterlogged' and 'Waterlogging' confusion in the context of rains

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In InE, you'll find a lot of headlines/sentences using 'waterlogging'. Say--

> 1. Waterlogging at the Central Railway Station caused traffic jam in the peak hours

Now, as I refer various dictionaries online, this seems to be an incorrect use. Because 'waterlog' is a verb

> [waterlog](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waterlog) - to fill with water....

In the context of heavy rain, the 'adjective' `waterlogged` seems to be more appropriate as in...

> 2. Waterlogged Central Railway Station caused a traffic jam in the peak hours

Now, 'waterlogging' as a gerund the way Indian media uses for a rain-filled area seems to be wrong. **Because**, waterlogging means something different. [It is more *agricultural*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterlogging_(agriculture)).

So, which one is proper? 1 or 2?

I'm interested what native speakers say when they want to refer to 'waterlogging' like this --

[image]

**Note:** 'waterlogging' search on Google images brings in actual result of fields and crops. So, this supports my question that 'waterlogging' referring to water-filled roads in rain is improper.

Answer (score 2):

"To waterlog" (to become full of water) is how the word is used in nautical contexts.  A ship's hold may waterlog. Certain boats are touted as having a design that "won't waterlog".

The most common day-to-day use of *waterlogged* in American English refers to things that are *soaked* or *saturated* with water. A rotten wooden board at the base of an exterior window might be waterlogged.  A sponge can be waterlogged. The ground and the soil can be waterlogged.

I think most native speakers of American English would say that the water in a waterlogged thing is not moving or flowing, but standing.  We would call the street in the photo a *flooded* street, and the headline would probably read  **Flooding Causes Traffic Jam**.

Comment: Aw..it's India... and there's no 'flood'. It's solely due to poor drainage system. The waves you see are 'created' by people/vehicle. Here are other images of what Indians call 'waterlogging' https://www.google.com/search?q=heavy+rain+mumbai&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CB0QsARqFQoTCIyVx6jC_cYCFVBYjgodzFoN_g&biw=1920&bih=945

Comment: Does Mumbai mean "wet place"?

Comment: No, Mumbai is an Indian city often 'flooded' with heavy rains. :)

Comment: yes, 'flooded' is better in this sense. I misunderstood it at first! +1

Comment: @MaulikV Yup. Flooded is excellent. Think of a flood as "a significant amount if liquid or water that is where it shouldn't be".

Comment: @Stephie yes.. it's true! :)